# Character to number conversion

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a column with for eg values: 
*.4176, 
*0.2734, 
$1.53, 
$122.00, 
D0.4645, 
D.2464, 
*0.3426, 
*.3426, 
$0.0/$2.50, 
-0.0/-2.50

I need to write a query to display only the numerical part in numerical format. I want to create a detail object for the main object in business object. 
I tried using translate but it has a lot of hardcoding and the slash is creating problem to convert it into TO_BINARY_DOUBLE. Is there anyother way to avoid hardcoding and still display numbers in numerical format?

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions

Comment: I am using the below query but the decimal points are going away with it.                                                                               regexp_replace(RSE_CD_D_SELL_MATRIX.DIR_COST_FORMULA,'( *[[:punct:]])','')

Comment: What output should be from this value?  -0.0/-2.50

Comment: can you write the output you require .

Comment: I would prefer both the values but then is it possibe to convert it in to double

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('*4176', ' */''', ' ') FROM DUAL;
```

This is the case when you have the symbol * in the column, just to get the idea. Perform some more translates for the other cases as well.

Cheers

Comment: I want all the three values in different columns. Like numeric alphabets and characters, and the mixed numbers in three different columns.

Comment: Didn't understand exactly what you want. A little example will do best.

Answer (score 0):

I require output in following format:
Cost Formula  Cost Formula Code Cost Formula Value  Cost calculation
$520.80             $                       520.8
*1                  *                       1
-0.0/-$20                                                  -0.0/-$20
+0.0/-$36                                                  +0.0/-$36

```
select 
cost_formula,
case
when TRANSLATE(COST_FORMULA,'1234567890.-+ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#%^&*()~`_[]{};<>:"*$',' ')='/' 
then ''
else TRANSLATE(COST_FORMULA,'1234567890.-+',' ')
END code,
case
when TRANSLATE(COST_FORMULA,'1234567890.-+ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#%^&*()~`_[]{};<>:"*$',' ')='/' 
then '0'
else TO_BINARY_DOUBLE(RTRIM(LTRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(COST_FORMULA),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#%^&*()~`_[]{};<>:"*$','0'))))
END value,
case 
when TRANSLATE(COST_FORMULA,'1234567890.-+ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#%^&*()~`_[]{};<>:"*$',' ')='/' 
then cost_formula
else ''
END Calculation
FROM RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS;
```

I am using this query to get the required format. But the numerical part is throwing the following error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got BINARY_DOUBLE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

And i want the numerical part to be as a float.